# Spring Batch Partition with Rest Service for slaves

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I am trying to use spring batch partition to process chunks of data using rest service. The documentation says the PartitionHandler implementations can be custom web services. Is there a default implementation of a web service partition handler similar to MessageChannelPartitionHandler?

Comment: Can you put more light on "chunks of data using rest service"

Comment: You can use Spring Integration to send REST API calls instead of using messaging middleware, however I'm not a SI expert so I'm unclear on the details of how.  If you add the `spring-integration` tag, I'm sure it will be picked up.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMinella I added the spring-integration tag. I did watch your talk on spring batch remote chunking/partitioning, it was really useful. I am trying to use Webservices to be my slaves. Just wanted to make sure its possible before I jump into it.

Comment: See my answer, please

Answer (score 0):

According Spring Batch Integration [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#remote-chunking) there is a `MessageChannelPartitionHandler`. That's fully enough to distinguish the master-slaves logic in your application using Spring Integration Channel Adapters downstream.

So, you need to configure that `MessageChannelPartitionHandler` and provide an appropriate consumer for send to the Web Service. The doc has a sample for JMS:

```
@Bean
public PartitionHandler partitionHandler() {
    MessageChannelPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new MessageChannelPartitionHandler();
    partitionHandler.setStepName("step1");
    partitionHandler.setGridSize(3);
    partitionHandler.setReplyChannel(outboundReplies());
    MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate();
    template.setDefaultChannel(outboundRequests());
    template.setReceiveTimeout(100000);
    partitionHandler.setMessagingOperations(template);
    return partitionHandler;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outboundJmsRequests() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("outboundRequests")
            .handle(Jms.outboundGateway(connectionFactory())
                    .requestDestination("requestsQueue"))
            .get();
}
```

But you definitely can do something similar to utilize `SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway` on the master side and `SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway` on the slaves side.